# Sass mix() function is giving error with valid color values

Tags: sass

**_theme-var.scss**

```
//color palette
$colors:(
    "primary":#ff0000,
    "secondary":#898989,
    "dark":#360000,
    "light":#ffaeae,
    "white":#fff
);
```

**style.scss**

```
@import "./theme-var";

@each $key,$val in $colors{
    .text-#{$key}-color{
        color: $val;
    }
    .bg-#{$key}-color{
        background-color:$val;
    }

    @for $i from 1 through 9{
        .text-#{$key}-color-light-#{$i}{
            color: mix(#ffff, #{$val},$i*10); // getting error for this line 
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**
It says that argument `$color-1` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color, I am passing color and also $val contains valid hax color what could be the reason for error?
**ERROR SCREENSHOT**
[image: MIX() FUNCTIONS ERROR MESSAGE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the interpolation on `#{$val}`. The variable is already a color and the interpolation seems to convert it to something else, that's why you get this error.

```
@for $i from 1 through 9 {
    .text-#{$key}-color-light-#{$i}{
        color: mix(#ffff, $val, $i*10);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way I get the error on `$color-2` not `$color-1`.

Comment: Thank you, so everything inside of #{} converted to string right and to keep it as a value I can should directly use it as a variable.

Comment: @stacknexo Humm, no I don't think so. I have assumed here that it converts it to as string but maybe it does something else, in any case it changes the type or you would not get this error. I will edit my answer since I'm not sure.